# Need to enable or disable tabs in RadTabStrip based on a session variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I'm working with Telerik Rad controls and I am trying to figure out the proper method to use when I need to enable or disable tabs in a RadTabStrip based on a session variable. You would think something like `RadTabStrip.Mytab.enabled = false` but you cant assign individual IDs to the tabs. I've read through the documentation but I cant seem to figur out how to do it based on a session.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
         // If the user is still in a session - Enable a certain Tab in the TabStrip and a certain PageView based on the current session variable.
        if (Session["PaymentStep"] != null)
        {
            switch (Session["PaymentStep"].ToString())
            {
                case "1":
                    // Need to select the "Bill" tab somehow and disable the rest
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
                case "2":
                    // Need to select the "Provider" tab somehow and disable the rest
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 2;
                    break;
                case "3":
                    // Need to select the "Payment" tab somehow and disable the rest
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 3;
                    break;
                case "4":
                    // Need to select the "Confirmation" tab somehow and disable the rest
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 4;
                    break;
                case "5":
                    // Need to select the "Reciept" tab somehow and disable the rest
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 5;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
```

Here's what I have so far in my page

```
<!-- TabStrip -->
    <div class="BillPayWrapper">
        <telerik:RadTabStrip ID="BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip" SelectedIndex="0" runat="server" MultiPageID="BillPayRadMultiPage" Align="Justify"
            Skin="Silk" CssClass="tabStrip" CausesValidation="false">
            <Tabs>
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Bill" PageViewID="Step1View"
                    ImageUrl="Images/1_normal.png"
                    SelectedImageUrl="Images/1_active.png" />
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Provider" PageViewID="Step2View"
                    ImageUrl="Images/2_normal.png"
                    SelectedImageUrl="Images/2_active.png"
                    DisabledImageUrl="Images/2_disable.png" />
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Payment" PageViewID="Step3View"
                    ImageUrl="Images/3_normal.png"
                    SelectedImageUrl="Images/3_active.png"
                    DisabledImageUrl="Images/3_disable.png" />
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Confirmation" PageViewID="Step4View"
                    ImageUrl="Images/4_normal.png"
                    SelectedImageUrl="Images/4_active.png"
                    DisabledImageUrl="Images/4_disable.png" />
                <telerik:RadTab runat="server" Text="Reciept" PageViewID="Step5View"
                    ImageUrl="Images/5_normal.png"
                    SelectedImageUrl="Images/5_active.png"
                    DisabledImageUrl="Images/5_disable.png" />
            </Tabs>
        </telerik:RadTabStrip>

        <!-- MultiPage Container -->
        <telerik:RadMultiPage ID="BillPayRadMultiPage" runat="server" SelectedIndex="0"
            CssClass="multiPage" BorderWidth="1" BorderColor="#888888">

            <!-- Step 1 PageView -->
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="Step1RadPageView" runat="server">
                <h1>Step 1 Content</h1>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <!-- // Step 1 PageView -->

            <!-- Step 2 PageView -->
            <telerik:RadPageView ID="Step2RadPageView" runat="server">
                <h1>Step 2 Content</h1>
            </telerik:RadPageView>
            <!-- // Step 2 PageView -->

        <!-- You get the idea -->
        </telerik:RadMultiPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind folks,

I seemed to have figured it out. I can enable or disabled the tabs by using their index. I found the correct syntax for this and applied it to my session check loop.

```
                    case "1":
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[0].Enabled = true;
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[0].Selected = true;
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[1].Enabled = false;
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[2].Enabled = false;
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[3].Enabled = false;
                    BillPayNavigationRadTabStrip.Tabs[4].Enabled = false;
                    BillPayRadMultiPage.SelectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
```